# If one column is matched with another column in different sheet then paste the Delivery date, purchasing document, still to be delivered quantity etc

Tags: excel, vba

I want that the "components" in "pending po" file match with the "components" in "source" file and if they matched then paste the "Purchasing document", "Still to be delivered quantity", "Delivery date", and "vendor/supplying plant" from "pending po" file to "source" file.
one more thing if more than one components in "pending po" file that were matched with the "source" file then the "Purchasing document", "Still to be delivered quantity", "Delivery date", and "vendor/supplying plant" of that delivery date will be showing next column of the previous one delivery date.
I am showing the sample date of what I want. I am new on this website and have little knowledge regarding vba.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moNNk.png)

In this picture if the same component have two different delivery dates, purchasing document, still to be delivered quantity, and vendor/supplying plant then it will show in the next column of the same component as shown in picture.
Kindly guide me about I will be very thankful to you

My working sheets are:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW9Pi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Qtr.png)

Comment: If you don't know *any* VBA, this is not a good place to start.  Typically questions here are to get help with *existing* code: if you need a tutorial  on VBA there are lots of good places to start, all available via Googling something like "VBA tutorial".   Once you have some code you can post back with your code, and a description of the specific problem(s) you're having with it.

Answer (score -1):

I can't make out exactly what you want, but it certainly sounds like something suitable for VLOOKUP functions rather than VBA.
Try something like https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/vlookup-guide/
(not mine)